# Adding title to annotations

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have this code that displays 4 points on a map with a custom image.  I have begun to learn that perhaps the way I structured it is not optimal but it is what I have.

Please help me to learn how to make the titles I created show up on the map with the custom poi when someone taps it.

I have two classes that work with the view.  The classes are MapAnnotation and LocationsViewController.

Here is the code for each.

**MapAnnotation.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation, MKMapViewDelegate> 
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    NSString * title;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

**MapAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
#import "LocationsViewController.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

**LocationsViewController.h**

```
#import "TechBookAppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface LocationsViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, MKAnnotation>
{
    IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation;
@end
```

**LocationsViewController.m**

```
#import "LocationsViewController.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
@interface LocationsViewController ()
@end

@implementation LocationsViewController

@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;
@synthesize title;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"app_icon_sm.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    worldView.showsUserLocation = NO;

    CLLocationCoordinate2D wisconsin = {.latitude =  45.620775, .longitude =  -89.47844};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pennsyvainia = {.latitude =  39.912417, .longitude =  -77.663268};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D nevada = {.latitude =  36.054362, .longitude =  -115.020470};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D texas = {.latitude =  32.555038, .longitude =  -94.295592};
    MapAnnotation *pinWI = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: wisconsin] ;
    MapAnnotation *pinPA = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: pennsyvainia];
    MapAnnotation *pinNV = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: nevada];
    MapAnnotation *pinTX = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: texas];
    //UIImage *star = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations_marker.png"];
                        //////////////////
    pinWI.title = @"Rhinelander, WI";///////
    pinPA.title = @"Chambersburg, PA";//////I dont understand why these do not output a
    pinNV.title = @"Henderson, NV";/////////title if the title property is a part of the
    pinTX.title = @"Marshall, TX";////////// MKAnnotation
                        //////////////////
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinTX];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinNV];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinWI];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinPA];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

I suppose I need a function to create the titles? I really am hoping I do not have to create more classes to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main question is:

> How to make the titles I created show up on the map with the custom poi when someone taps it.

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, you need to set the `canShowCallout` property of the annotation view to `YES` (the default is `NO`):

```
if (annotationView == nil)
{
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation...
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;  // <-- add this line
}
```

Some additional comments unrelated to the question:

1. In MapAnnotation.h, this class will only be implementing `MKAnnotation`, not `MKMapViewDelegate` so remove it from the protocol list to avoid potential compiler warnings and to make the code clearer and cleaner:

   ```
   @interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>
   ```
2. In MapAnnotation.m, you don't need the `#import "LocationsViewController.h"`.  Remove it.
3. In LocationsViewController.h, this class will *not* be implementing `MKAnnotation` so remove it from the protocol list to avoid potential compiler warnings and to make the code clearer and cleaner:

   ```
   @interface LocationsViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
   ```
4. Also in LocationsViewController.h, it's unnecessary to declare the delegate methods you'll be implementing.  You can remove the `viewForAnnotation` *declaration*.
5. In LocationsViewController.m, the `@synthesize`s for `coordinate` and `title` don't belong here.  Remove them.

Comment: Anna returns to save the day again. I learned a lot from this. thank you very much Anna. this worked beautifully. The additional comments are extremely appreciated! thank you!! Very Helpful!!

Comment: any other pointers or comments regarding my current configuration? any and all information is very much appreciated.

Comment: QUICK QUESTION: How would I remove the prompt that loads with the map which asks to access the users location?

Comment: You can't access the user's location without iOS prompting for permission.  This prompt should only be coming up once anyway unless user keeps disabling location permission in Settings.

Comment: I have no need to know the users location thats why I ask. with location accepted this shouldn't be a problem then. thank you.

Comment: Ok, if it's asking even though you're setting showsUserLocation to NO, then check map view settings in the xib/storyboard.  Make sure "Shows User Location" is unchecked.  If it's checked there, it will cause the prompt as soon as it loads the xib before it gets to your code that turns it off.  (It it's unchecked in the xib, you don't need to turn it off in code.)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)locatePlaceonMap:(NSDictionary*)dic
{
[map_bar setScrollEnabled:YES];
map_bar.delegate = self;
MKCoordinateRegion zoomIn = map_bar.region;

zoomIn.span.latitudeDelta  = 0.1f;
zoomIn.span.longitudeDelta  = 0.1f;

zoomIn.center.latitude = ApplicationDelegate.latitude;
zoomIn.center.longitude = ApplicationDelegate.longitude;

[map_bar setRegion:zoomIn animated:NO];

MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
annotation.title = [dic valueForKey:@"vName"];
annotation.subtitle = [dic valueForKey:@"t_long_address"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D newlocation = [map_bar.userLocation coordinate];
newlocation.latitude=[[dic valueForKey:@"dLat"]doubleValue];
newlocation.longitude=[[dic valueForKey:@"dLong"]doubleValue];
annotation.coordinate = newlocation;
[map_bar addAnnotation:annotation];
}


#pragma mark MkMapViewDelegate Methods

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:   (id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
static NSString *defaultPinID = @"ReusedPin";
pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];

if ( pinView == nil )
    pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) {

    return nil;

}else{
    pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin_trophy.png"];
    pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}
pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
pinView.animatesDrop = NO;

return pinView;
}
```